# "Unexpected color space /R11" while parsing a PDF file with text and image

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, text-extraction

System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Unexpected color space /R11
  Source=itextsharp
  StackTrace:
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.GetComponentsPerPixel(PdfName colorSpaceName)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.ComputeBytesPerRow(PdfDictionary imageDictionary)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.ParseUnfilteredSamples(PdfDictionary imageDictionary, PdfContentParser ps)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.ParseInlineImageSamples(PdfDictionary imageDictionary, PdfContentParser ps)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.ParseInlineImage(PdfContentParser ps)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.ProcessContent[E](Int32 pageNumber, E renderListener)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, Int32 pageNumber, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy)
       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, Int32 pageNumber)
       at PDF_PdfToText.extractText(String src, String dest) in d:\QC\Backup\NRK\Current\QConform nrk - 2010\PDF\PdfToText.aspx.cs:line 29
       at PDF_PdfToText.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\QC\Backup\NRK\Current\QConform nrk - 2010\PDF\PdfToText.aspx.cs:line 17
       at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:

Comment: Ouch.  Could you please format that a bit?

Answer (score 0):

iText's inline image parser has undergone some work recently.  If you're not using 5.0.5, you might be missing a relevant bug fix.

The whole .pdf.parser package is still under development unfortunately.  OTOH, if you do have the latest-n-greatest, and are still getting this exception, you've got an iText[sharp] bug.  Head on over to the [itext-questions mailing list](http://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/itext-questions) and post your stack trace along with the PDF that causes it if at all possible.  We'll take care of it.

Alternatively, you can [report the bug via the sourceforge tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=15255&atid=115255).  Attached files there aren't Broadcast To The World, so you might be more comfortable with that.